# Music sync from Ubuntu 20.04 to Iphone (RhythmBox won't Recognize Iphone)

Tags: 20.04, sync, rhythmbox, playonlinux, iphone

New linux user using Ubuntu 20.04 (from windows 10). Trying to sync to and from my iphone and after doing some research and trying several options I have installed the required repositories (libimobiledevice, ifuse, libgpod, etc) to mount and pair my iphone to Ubunutu. Problem is RhythmBox won't recognize the device (it won't show up). However the iphone does shows up in the filesystem. I tried using Wine and PlayOnLinux to install Itunes but encoutered errors.

Ubuntu Software Store does not provide Amarok or Banshee for Ubunutu 20.04 from what I can find so i'm unable to try other music/audio players as alternatives.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. In order to give any help you need to be clear.  What are the exact things you have installed. do not just say etc. *libimobiledevice, ifuse, libgpod, etc What errors? *Wine and PlayOnLinux to install Itunes but encoutered errors